# Iron Router Controller Inheritance Patterns

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Lets say I've got the following structure in a Meteor project

lib/ 
|_ base_router_controllers.js 
|_ post_router_controllers.js 
|_ task_router_controllers.js

**base_router_controllers.js**

```
JsonController = RouteController.extend({
    action: function() {
        //do things
    }
});
```

**post_router_controllers.js**

```
PostController = JsonController.extend({
    action: function() {
        //do post things
    }
});
```

**task_router_controllers.js**

```
TaskController = JsonController.extend({
    action: function() {
        //do task things
    }
});
```

Without adding JsonControlleer  to both post_router_controllers.js and task_router_controllers.js the post and task router controller files can't find the json controller. How can inherit JsonController without duplicating the controller code in multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pattern that worked for me:

**From the Meteor docs**

*Files in subdirectories are loaded before files in parent directories, so that files in the deepest subdirectory are loaded first (after lib), and files in the root directory are loaded last (other than main.*).*

/lib 
|__ /base/
     |__ base_router_controllers.js
|__ post_router_controllers.js
|__ task_router_controllers.js

Just putting the base RouteController(s) in a deeper directory.

Answer (score 2):

Files are loaded in filename order. I would simply put the controllers in the same file – in the order you need them, of course.

(At any rate, the `lib` folder is not really for routers. I usually use `/client/routers/router.js`.)

Comment: sure I could use lib/routers/ -- /client/routers/ won't work for my project as i've got a few server side routes.